SLAM Localization node updates global costmap causing distortion
I'm currently trying to use the SLAM toolbox localization node to allow a robot to localize itself and navigate an environment. Everything appears to load in correctly, with the initial RViz screen displaying the expected information. However, after publishing a goal pose in RViz, the rover will begin to move and eventually cause the global costmap to become distorted. The initial map and distorted map can be seen below. From the terminal, I've only found one message that seems to be related which is the following:
[planner_server-5] [INFO] [1729005546.064768186] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 759 X 711 at 0.050000 m/pix

This would indicate to me that somehow the map resizing is breaking the global map, but am unsure how to resolve this. I'm happy to provide any launch/config files used, but they are currently the simulation configuration as provided by the Rover Robotics repository and can be referenced there.



Does this robot include multiple Lidar sensors? I had a similar issue when using a laser_scan_merger package, but it did not occur when only using one lidar.

@EthanLeBlanc The simulation is configured to use a single Lidar scanner. While the platform is driving before the global costmap update occurs, all the lidar scan data appears to be updating and displaying as expected.
